# Costing on Snowflake to process 10 -100 GB of data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to find the cost of DWH, based on data. e.g. if I have to process 10GB data in snowflake how to calculate which node is required and how long ?

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like an easy problem to solve with the free trial: Upload 10GB of data, run a query, see how long it took. 

Do you have more specifics?

Comment: there is also the aspect, of is it a "single 10GB process" each day, or 10GB across 24 hours, in 5 minute batches. And if the latter, will each batch, just load new rows, to alter old rows, or will the processing need to update running totals.. But if it helps we were processing 1 billion rows, and doing the latter described processing, and reads also, all on a extra small for the first year of getting our full pipeline up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unanswerable.

1. It depends on what processing you are doing to the data
2. It depends on how fast you want the data to be processed
3. It depends on whether the processing can take advantage of additional nodes

Even if you knew all this information, you could only guesstimate what it would cost. Given the cost would be minimal anyway, the most cost effective approach would be to try it and see.

Comment: Thanks NickW, I know best approach is try and see. but for  very high level estimates,  need to know if 10 or 100 GB data processing  in 2 hours which node is good.